# SQL Server Loop Over Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a view `vwDocumentLinks` with data as shown below:

[image: View Results]

I have another table `RiskTypes` with data as below.

[image: Risk Types Table]

The link between the table & viewis : `Idx25  = Risk Type` and `LinkDocNo = DocumentType`. What I am trying to achieve is to get `DocumentType` in `RiskTypes` that's not in the view `vwDocumentLinks` foreach `BaseValue` and where `Idx25  = RiskType`. An example using a single `BaseValue` will be:

```
SELECT * FROM RiskTypeDocuments WHERE RiskType = 'BUSINESS LIMITED COMPANY' AND DocumentType NOT IN (SELECT LINKDOCNO FROM DBO.VWLINKS WHERE BaseValue = '00007573-1637-4B8E-9374-730AF58BCFB6')
```

[image: query result]

I tried the below query and it's not working as expected. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am a newbie in SQL

```
SELECT dbo.RiskTypeDocuments.DocumentType,
dbo.RiskTypeDocuments.RiskType,
dbo.vwLinks.BaseValue AS Document
FROM dbo.vwLinks LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.RiskTypeDocuments ON dbo.vwLinks.LinkDocNo = 
dbo.RiskTypeDocuments.DocumentType AND  dbo.vwLinks.Idx25 = 
dbo.RiskTypeDocuments.RiskType
WHERE dbo.RiskTypeDocuments.DocumentType IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Document
```

NB: I can't change the schema. I can only create views from the existing tables.
**Sample Data from the two datasets**: [vwDocumentLinks & RiskTypeDocuments](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vBFawLe8eOMpVXk3oKLn1odvL8KBHasn)

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: I just tried removing the `WHERE` clause, the result is almost the same just that other columns return `NULL`

Comment: Do you want those new values to be returned? If yes, keep LEFT JOIN. If not, switch to INNER JOIN. (The WHERE clause isn't needed in any case.)

Comment: You are right, the returned results are still the same after switching to `inner join`. But again, that's not the desired result

Comment: Sample data as formatted text instead of images would be a great +. Also base values like 1, 2, 3 instead of 172371237127124783123, 717617837373737373763 and 837373739828936374893 make things easier.

Comment: Added sample data from the two data sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.DocumentType,
a.RiskType,
b.BaseValue AS Document 
FROM dbo.RiskTypeDocuments as a
INNER JOIN (Select distinct Idx25, BaseValue from vwDocumentLinks) as b on b.Idx25 = a.RiskType
where a.DocumentType not in (Select LINKDOCNO  from vwDocumentLinks as c where c.basevalue = b.BaseValue )
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, this query is returning the desired result

Comment: @TakudzwaMawarire Welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the records which don't exist in the view then
Try like this

```
SELECT d.DocumentType,
       d.RiskType,
       v.BaseValue 
FROM dbo.vwLinks AS v 
OUTER JOIN dbo.RiskTypeDocuments d ON v.LinkDocNo = d.DocumentType AND v.vwLinks.Idx25 =d.RiskType
WHERE v.BaseValue IS NULL 
ORDER BY DocumentType
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but this ain't returning the desired response **for each** `BaseValue`. As in the example given, i want the result **for each**  `Basevalue`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `NOT EXISTS`. It takes a little to get your head around, but the idea is to have what is called a correlated subquery. The subquery is joined to the main query, hence the term correlated.

```
SELECT *
FROM RiskTypeDocuments
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM vwDocumentLinks
    WHERE RiskTypeDocuments.RiskType = vwDocumentLinks.idx25
          AND RiskTypeDocuments.DocumentType = vwDocumentLinks.LinkDocNo
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan. This is returning an overall result, not the one **foreach** `BaseValue` as desired.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by one foreach BaseValue - perhaps you can provide a clearer example explaining what you are after - it doesn't seem to be easy to follow.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM RiskTypeDocuments WHERE RiskType = 'BUSINESS LIMITED COMPANY' AND DocumentType NOT IN (SELECT LINKDOCNO FROM DBO.VWLINKS WHERE BaseValue = '00007573-1637-4B8E-9374-730AF58BCFB6')` is the example i have given in my question. maybe a simpler question would be how to make this query work without specifying the two specifies values `BaseValue` && `RiskType` but still grouping results by `BaseValue` && `RiskType`. Sorry I am used to hiding all these queries behind Entity Framework hence my terminology. I hope am not adding more confusion.

Comment: Provide a complete but small set of source data for both tables and a complete set of expected results. Do not include irrelevant data, do not exclude relevant data

Comment: Edited the question to provide link to sample data